# Picking up a certain string pattern without regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, macros

I have a scenario where I have a variety of C++ files with a specific macro:

```
__EXTERNALIZE(Name, File)
```

This macro is empty, it does nothing. But I want to write an external tool that scans one or many input files for this macro and do something once it finds that.

To clarify, here is a bit of pseudo-c:

```
typedef struct {
    char* varname;
    char* filename;
} MacroInfo_s;
FILE* fh = fopen("./source.cpp",'r');
while(read_untill_macro(fh) && !feof(fh)) {
    MacroInfo_s m;
    fill_macro_info(&m, fh);
    // Do something with m.varname and m.filename
}
```

C++11 isn't broadly available. For instance, VS 2010 does not provide it at all, and that is the lowest I want to target on the Windows side. On my OS X 10.10, everything is fine. That is also why I mainly don't want to use Regexp, since I would need an extra library. And that just to react to a single macro within a few files seems a bit of an overkill.

What would be a good aproach to make this possible to work?

Comment: I wouldn't use C++ for this, but a scripting language

Comment: I would use `grep`.  Can you clarify why you want to write a tool for this?  It appears that your main purpose is to identify source files containing this macro and potentially remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is using [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read up to every open paren `(` and then check that string for your macro.

Then another [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read up to the closing paren `)` should extract your macro's parameters.

**A bit like this:**

```
const std::string EXTERNALIZE = "__EXTERNALIZE";

int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    for(char** arg = argv + 1; *arg; ++arg)
    {
        std::cout << "Processing file: " << *arg << '\n';

        std::ifstream ifs(*arg);

        std::string text;
        while(std::getline(ifs, text, '('))
        {
            // use rfind() to check the text leading up to the open paren (
            if(text.rfind(EXTERNALIZE) != text.size() - EXTERNALIZE.size())
                continue;

            std::cout << "found macro:" << '\n';

            // now read the parameters up to the closing paren )
            std::getline(ifs, text, ')');

            // here are the macro's parameters
            std::cout << "parameters: " << text << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat! I wasn't aware `getline` had such powers. :)